# Share strings between Android and iOs

Tags: android, ios, resources

I'm looking for options to share the ui strings between native Android and iOS developments. Any ideas or tools?

EDIT: I basically want to use the same strings for all the UI elements like buttons, messages, etc. in order to both applications are equal and maintain the strings only in one place

Comment: Please rephrase your question and tell us a bit better what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [JSON](http://www.json.org/). It is a pretty standard format, and both iOS and Android handle it nicely.
For each language you cold have a file in the form

```
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

in iOS you would get a NSDictionary (mutable or not, as you wish)

Comment: Thanks, but for example in Android I'd need to use them from the xml files using "@string/my_string1" and with json can't do it

Comment: Ok, so if you just want to have the native formats, you could mantain the iOS string resource and convert it to the android format with [this tool](http://localise.biz/free/converter/ios-to-android)